# Style not appearing for Material UI Cards?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styling

I'm currently trying to override the default Material UI classes by using useStyles and using a classname of titleSection. Currently, I want the titleSection to be bold and be Roboto font, but those aren't being applied.

Here is my card:

```
function ImageCard(props: ImageCardProps) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card>

      <CardHeader title={props.title} className={classes.titleSection} />
 
    </Card>
  );
}
```

And here is my useStyles:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    
    
    titleSection:{
        paddingBottom: 0,
        fontWeight:'bolder',
        fontFamily:'Roboto',
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: Create a codesandbox.io demo of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The MUI docs are really good for explaining this: https://material-ui.com/api/card-header/

You can use the 'classes' property and target the title css rule name that wraps the typography component.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    title: {
      paddingBottom: 0,
      fontWeight: 'bolder',
      fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
    },
  })
);

function ImageCard(props: ImageCardProps) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader title={props.title} classes={{ title: classes.title }} />
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Or if you want this to be global, take a look at the MUI theme object and theme override docs:

- https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/
- https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#5-global-theme-variation